# nodeValue complete retrieval

Tags: php, html

So I am using [nodeValue](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php) to get the value of a div in PHP using the DOM commands. The problem is the content of that div also has link like

```
<a href="www.something.com">Link!!!</a>
```

and nodeValue does not print `href="www.something.com` instead it prints `Link!!!` is there any way to use the php DOM manulpulation to get all the atributes of all the html tags in area? So that if the text I was retreving was

```
<a href="www.something.com">Link!!!</a>
```

It would actauly return `<a href="www.something.com">Link!!!</a>`

I can not specially search for the `<a>` tag and then get the href value from that because the content could be varying greatly and there are a lot of links so it would not be practical(b/c of variation of way link works and such).

**The html I am trying to get is not on the same domain. Thus the same domain policy prohibits jquery from working. Don't worry I know what I am doing, I am not looking for alternative solutions**

Comment: @JamundFerguson Thats not the issue though, that was just an example. The issue is that the command does not return the attributes of a tag when using nodeValue.

Comment: this seems like a job for [jQuery](http://jquery.com)

Comment: @ShanRobertson I guess I forgot to mention that it is not on the same domain. Thus the same domain policy prohibits jquery from working. Don't worry I know what I am doing, I am not looking for alternative solutions.

Comment: @Noah Huppert fair enough, this just seems like a painful way to do it. But if you can't you can't!

Comment: @ShanRobertson Ik. I cringed when I realized I had to use php DOM commands to get the html. :p

Comment: Beware of [the "X Y Problem"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): your question here is not actually about `nodeValue`, which you have discovered *doesn't* do what you want, it is about how to get a node/element complete with attributes using DOM functions. Sometimes, framing a question correctly takes you a long way towards finding an answer.

Comment: @IMSoP at the time of writing the question I thought that maybe there was an option that you you could add to nodeValue that would make it do what I wanted. Since them I have learned otherwise.

Comment: @NoahHuppert Nonetheless, it's always best to start the question with what you're trying to achieve, and *then* list what you've tried so far. In this case, you put `nodeValue` right there in the title, suggesting you were thinking too much about what you couldn't do and not what you wanted to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I chatted with some people on the forum and they suggested doing this

```
$node -> ownerDocument -> SaveHTMl($node)
```

And that seemed to work.